Mentioning PhD Admission on Resume When Prioritizing Industry Job Search
I am currently completing my master's degree. I have been admitted to a PhD program, and I may enroll in it, but I am primarily looking for a job. I would rather work in industry first in order to gain experience before potentially committing to a PhD program, as I am not yet certain if a PhD is the right path for me. My goal is to get some job experience first. When applying for jobs, should I state on my resume that I have been admitted and may enroll in the PhD program in order to demonstrate my academic achievement? Or would that give the impression that my main interest is an academic career rather than the industry job I am seeking? I want to highlight being admitted to the PhD as an accomplishment, but I don't want employers to think I am solely focused on academia if my priority right now is finding an industry position.

"please hire me although I may just go back to school, lol" is not a winning strategy.

@TigerGuy - depends a lot on where. I’ve hired folks intending to get a PhD as technologists in my research group, and if I get a few years it’s good.


I want to highlight being admitted to the PhD as an accomplishment

I wouldn't see it that way. If, let's say, you were admitted because of your good grades, then these good grades are the actual accomplishment and already are in your CV.
So, in my opinion, you don't have much to gain by this.
From the point of view of the employer, the information tells them two things:

You're more likely to quit relatively soon to pursue a PhD. This makes you less attractive, especially because you're a fresh graduate who needs to be trained first.
You're less likely to accept an offer if you get one, which is a waste of resources in the hiring process.

You can't really avoid giving the information because if you're asked in an interview if you've applied for a PhD, you probably don't want to lie. But in an interview, you can at least explain your intentions in detail.
If you put it on your CV, you give the information earlier than you have to and thereby decrease your chance of even getting an interview. Point 2 is more important at this stage because they have not yet "invested" an interview in you.

That of depends a lot on what type of job and subject we are talking about. In an industry where Ph.D. in the work force (bio tech, pharma) are relatively "normal" than it's ok to mention it. Chances are many companies in this type of industry will have "degree while you work" programs that you could leverage.
In an industry where Ph.Ds. are rare (engineering, marketing), that could indeed backfire. The Ph.D. isn't particular interesting to the employer and they prefer candidates that commit to a full industry career starting now.


I would rather work in industry first in order to gain experience
before potentially committing to a PhD program, as I am not yet
certain if a PhD is the right path for me.

Everything you put in your resume and cover letter is supposed to help you get an interview. Then the interview and the documents are to help you get a good offer.
Putting things that make them concerned about you becoming a long term employee doesn't help your job search.
Telling them you have been accepted to a PhD program makes them wonder when is the start date. They will wonder if the program is full-time or part-time. They can always ask you these questions or they may just reject your resume/application and go to the next one in the queue.

I want to highlight being admitted to the PhD as an accomplishment,
but I don't want employers to think I am solely focused on academia if
my priority right now is finding an industry position.

While getting into a program is an accomplishment, highlighting it screams that you want to work on the new degree. Even mentioning it tells them that.
Some positions will count a degree towards required years of experience, but getting accepted into a program doesn't gain you anything.


When applying for jobs, should I state on my resume that I have been
admitted and may enroll in the PhD program in order to demonstrate my
academic achievement?

"I have been admitted to a PhD program and I may enroll."
That tells me that you aren't sure you want a job and you may be starting school soon instead.
I would not suggest you put that in your resume if you actually want a job.
